# Simple console graphics in C

Tags: c, graphics, dos

I am new to C and I would like to know if it is possible to make colorful console menus with simple graphics, like old DOS programs used to look. I am programming on Windows PC and portability is not important for this one.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: You should tell us what you tried and we will try to help you fix it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/) which is a dos/windows curses implementation (curses does all the console richness in unix/linux environments).